# How to change names on items in project template so they get the same name as the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, desktop-application

I want a class in the project template to get the same name as the project when a new project is created based on the template.

Ive changed the TargetFileName in vstemplate to use the parameter $safeprojectname$.

Ive also also changed the csproj file to use the same parameter for the specific class name.

After that I select all the files in the unzipped project and zip.

Then I open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS" as an administrator and enter "devenv /installvstemplates" and run.

But when I then create a new project from the template the class has the same name as before I made these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I did wrong.

I missed that I had to move the edited template to "MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates" for changes to apply.